# Why wouldn't a broken wand work?

Tags: harry-potter, wandlore

It is clear that a wand that has been broken will not work properly and is very hard to mend. The only examples of mended wands are Harry's phoenix wand, which he mended using the Elder wand, and (though it is not explicitly said) Hagrid's wand, which apparently was mended by the Elder wand as well.

However, a wand is nothing more than a tool to channel the magical energy of a wizard. They can be made with different kinds of wood, with various magical cores, and (most important to my point) many shapes and lengths. Coming to think about it, and depending on the way the wand is broken, a single piece of a broken wand seems to be simply a shorter wand of the same wood and core. This is of course a logical and non-canon-supported conclusion. Maybe the wood needs to undergo some kind of process before you install it around the core, and this is damaged when the wand is broken? Maybe there is a missing process in the manufacturing of a wand?

Why wouldn't a broken wand act as a shorter wand?

Comment: Because it's broken, duh.

Comment: @Roberto - I came here to make an identical comment.

Comment: Presumably in the same way that a broken water pipe stops working. The pressuse in the system (in this instance the user's magic) wouldn't reach the tap

Comment: @Valorum, did you bother reading the question? A broken wand is nothing like a water pipe. Also, a pipe can be mended.

Comment: @havakok What if a wand is like a battery? A broken battery doesnt work. It must have a positive and a negative pole.

Comment: @Valorum Ditto.

Comment: What if a wand is like a rooster? One half-a-rooster is good for making soup, but not much use as a rooster.

Comment: Wasn't Ron's wand fixed with spellotape?

Comment: @Pete - But still didn't work properly

Comment: When was it said/implied/insinuated that Hagrid's broken wand was ever mended by the Elder Wand and not just tucked inside his umbrella?

Comment: Where does it say in the literature that a wand is nothing like a water pipe? It’s magic. It could work in any number of ways. Maybe it’s exactly like a water pipe. Maybe there is a custom gecko wand that works ok if you break it and even regrows its own tip. A broken wand doesn’t work because that’s one of the ways that JKR decided magic would work (or not work).

Comment: @DoscoJones Half a magnet is still a magnet. I guess the problem is down to finding the right analogue.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ftomw87g61Y

Comment: The real question is, why does an unbroken wand work?

Comment: @ToddWilcox I am not saying that it is nothing like a water pipe. I am saying that we can't assume that it is because it is not established anywhere. And if we are not sure of that, we can't be sure that a broken wand is not simply a short wand. B.T.W, a broken pipe can be used as a shorter pipe in some constellations.

Comment: @havakok We can be pretty sure a broken wand isn't simply a short wand. Ron had his wand broken. It didn't work. Also, the Ministry breaks wands of expelled and punished people. It wouldn't make any sense to break wands if the pieces still work.

Comment: @Roberto, the question is why. The reasoning behind it not working is not clear.

Answer (score 9):

While we don't know the specific *mechanism* by which a snapped wand ceases working, we do know what happens if a wand is inexpertly patched. It has a tendency to leak magic, to fail to work correctly (with unpleasant-smelling consequences), to backfire and, in extremis, to explode.

> Ron was having far worse problems. He had patched up his wand with
> some borrowed Spellotape, but it seemed to be damaged beyond repair.
> It kept crackling and sparking at odd moments, and every time Ron
> tried to transfigure his beetle it engulfed him in thick grey smoke
> which smelled of rotten eggs. Unable to see what he was doing, Ron
> accidentally squashed his beetle with his elbow and had to ask for a
> new one. Professor McGonagall wasn’t pleased.

and

> He raised Ron’s Spellotaped wand high over his head and yelled,
> ‘Obliviate!’ The wand exploded with the force of a small bomb. Harry
> flung his arms over his head and ran, slipping over the coils of snake
> skin, out of the way of great chunks of tunnel ceiling which were
> thundering to the floor. Next moment, he was standing alone, gazing at
> a solid wall of broken rock.

I think we can reasonably assume that a wand takes magic from the user, channels it down the core and out of the tip of the wand. If the wand and core are damaged, the magic won't come out of the end properly or will come out prematurely along the body of the wand, interacting with the body of the wand or the user in some fashion.

[image]

Comment: +1 for 'Pew Pew'

Comment: Why do you say a broken wand 'leaks magic'? While I can agree with the other descriptions of a snapped wand, nowhere can I find it 'leaks' anything.  Personally, I do not think we can reasonably assume that a wand takes the magic from the user, channels it down the core and out of the tip of the wand. Why is this a reasonable assumption? and if it is, my point stand that if you saw a wand or break it relatively straight, it would work as a shorter wand.

Comment: @Righter Thanks, I actually wasn't able to read what was the red text on the tip of the wand.

Comment: @havakok Think of it a bit like a gardening water hose. If you cut it, it's not going to work so well anymore. And if you try jury rigging it with whatever you can get your hands on, it's going to leak. While we can't tell for sure that the magic comes from the user, we know that people can cast spells without a wand. I suppose the wand serves as some kind of catalyst to better cast spells. And when it's broken... well, it's unlikely to serve its purpose so well anymore.